# crypto-js aes can't decrypt what it encrypted

Tags: javascript, encryption, encoding, cryptography, cryptojs

Hello I'm trying to decrypt a encrypted aes string with crypto-js but it seems like it doesn't work right.

I'm using:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script>
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");

    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
</script>
```

But my results are:

```
encrypted: U2FsdGVkX19whKq54yOQt3l1erbtEtn/M0qJjAH+E/E=
decrypted: 4d657373616765
```

My expectation was the it returns back "Message". What am I missing?

Comment: Also 3DES doesn't work either

Comment: Don't use 3DES for new work, use AES.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return type of all `CryptoJS.<blockcipher>.decrypt()` functions is a `WordArray` which is the native representation of binary data in CryptoJS. When you force it to be printed (automatically calling `toString()`), the binary data that it contains will be Hex encoded.

If you want to have a different encoding, then you need to specify it. Here are some examples:

```
console.log(decrypted.toString()); // Hex encoded
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)); // Hex encoded
console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(decrypted)); // Hex encoded

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)); // UTF-8 encoded
console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted)); // UTF-8 encoded

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)); // Base64 encoded
console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(decrypted)); // Base64 encoded
```