# Can't decrypt password using CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I am trying to make an encryption using CryptoJS. The encryption seems to work fine, but when I decrypt the password, I do not get the initial plain text password.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var password = "";
function noSsl()
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#dialog").dialog({ show: 'fade', hide: 'fade' });
    });
}
function savePassword()
{
    password = document.getElementById("ap").value;
    alert("Initial password: " + password);
    enPassword = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, <?php echo '"'.$currentAdk.'"'; ?>);
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#ap").slideToggle("slow");
        $("#sp").slideToggle("slow");
        $("#sp").remove();
    });
    alert("Encrypted: " + enPassword);
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(enPassword, <?php echo '"'.$currentAdk.'"'; ?>)
    alert("Decrypted: " + decrypted);
}
</script>
```

Here are the results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please try `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(enPassword, <?php echo '"'.$currentAdk.'"'; ?>).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);`?

Comment: That worked, thank you

Comment: Please post it as an answer, so i can validate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [crypto-js aes can't decrypt what it encrypted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418178/crypto-js-aes-cant-decrypt-what-it-encrypted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the decrypted, plaintext password using CryptoJS, you need to use:

```
var decryptedPlaintextPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(enPassword, <?php echo '"'.$currentAdk.'"'; ?>).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```