# How to decrypt AES with a known KEY and IV using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I'm trying to learn CryptoJS using https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/
It shows how to encrypt with AES but it does not how how to decrypt using both KEY and IV. I'm looking at the below code.

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script>
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f');
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f');

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key, { iv: iv });
```

I have tried the below code:

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { iv: iv });
```

However, it gives me the wrong plain text. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

The output I receive is:

```
4d657373616765
```

The correct plain text should obviously be:

```
Message
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't decrypt password using CryptoJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646564/cant-decrypt-password-using-cryptojs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII ;-) http://www.italysoft.com/utility/converters/asciifull.gif

The output are binary ASCII characters.

4d = M
65 = e

etc...

Comment: Link is dead now.

Answer (score 1):

As hotips said, it's hex for ASCII, CryptoJS has built-in encoders. You can stringify it to Utf8 doing this:

`var utf8Decrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted);`

For other encoders see:

[CryptoJS Encoders](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Encoders)